# C Multi-Dimensional Vectors; LinearSearch

Tags: c++, search, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a function that searches through a multidimensional vector for an item that I want. Whats happening though is that the search only compares the first item in the vector -> vectorName[0][0] and not any of the following ones ie vectorName[0][1] and so on. How do I fix this function so that it would search through all of the items in the multidimensional vector and compare it with the key?

```
        void linearSearch(vector<vector<string>> &vectorName, string key)
        {
            for (int i =0; i < vectorName.size(); i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k<vectorName.size(); k++)
                {
                    if (key == vectorName[i][k])
                    {
                        cout << "Found " << vectorName[i][k] << " at "
                             << i << ","<< k <<endl;           
                    }     
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, maybe the `vectorName` is not square, so change:

```
for (int k = 0; k<vectorName.size(); k++)
```

to

```
for (int k = 0; k<vectorName[i].size(); k++)
                            ^^^
```

Comment: I the OP's specific case that would happen if the outer vector only has one inner vector.

Comment: No I tested the vector, and it has 3 things within it. MM. was right. Thanks.